# Pre-trained Language Models: Parameters, data, method?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, language-model, roberta-language-model

I am doing a research on pre-trained LMs, specifically the following LMs:

- BERT
- ALBERT
- RoBERTa
- XLNet
- DistilBERT
- BigBird
- ConvBERT

I am looking for information to compare these LMs like: number of parameters, layers, data on which they were pre-trained...

In other words, I want to extend the following table to the other LMs:

[image]

But I can't find information online! Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for each of these models, possibly even the research paper associated with it.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan actually that's exactly what I am doing, I just thought maybe I can use some help tracking these informations to finish fast.